# I can't retrieve data from MySQL database using a JSP file and receive a java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long error

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, mysql-workbench

I am trying to retrieve values from MySQL database using my JSP file; however, I am receiving the following error:

java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

MySQL database:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS cars;

CREATE DATABASE cars;

USE cars;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS manufacturer;

CREATE TABLE manufacturer (
manufacturerID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
manufacturer varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (manufacturerID)
);

INSERT INTO manufacturer (manufacturer) VALUES ('Nissan'),('Honda'),
('Ford'),('Hyundai'),('Volkswagen'),('Chevrolet');
```

JSP File:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <% out.println("JSP Database");%>
    <%!
        Connection conn;
        Statement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;
    %>
    <table border="1">
      <tr> <th>Manufacturer ID</th> <th>Manufacturer Name</th></tr>

       <%
  try{
    String connectionUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cars";
    String connectionUser="root";
    String connectionPassword="admin";

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPassword);

        stmt=conn.createStatement();
        rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from manufacturer");

        while(rs.next()) { 
            out.println(rs.getString("manufacturer")); %>
           <tr> 
            <td> <% out.println(rs.getInt("manufacturerID")); %> </td> 
            <td> <%=rs.getString("manufacturer") %></td> 
           </tr>        
    <%
        }  
     }

   catch(Exception cnfex){
         cnfex.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally{
         if(rs!=null) rs.close();
         if(stmt!=null) stmt.close();
         if(conn!=null) conn.close();
         }
        %>
        </table>
```

Console:

```
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3590)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.JSPFile_jsp._jspService(JSPFile_jsp.java:141)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1374)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:1019)
    ... 43 more
```

[Expected Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z4B0.jpg)

[Project Folders:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l29jB.jpg)

What I have done to troubleshoot:

1. I have moved the sql jar file from the Build Path to the lib folder under Web Content
2. Run this project on a friend's computer (it works perfectly fine!)
3. Reinstalled eclipse

I understand this is not the recommended way to use JDBC nor JSP. This is an example that was done in class and it works for everyone except me. I've also encountered the same problem when trying to retrieve data from the database using Servlets.

Any help on how I can troubleshoot this issue is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems like a setup problem.  Can you describe the differences between your friend's computer and yours? What versions of java and mysql are you using.  When you say the software worked fine on the other computer, was it your exact version?  There has to be a difference there that would help figure this out.

Comment: We are both using MySQL Workbench Community 6.3.9 CE, the same .jar file mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar. We are also using the same java version "1.8.0_151". I am using eclipse Neon as opposed to the newest version (Oxygen). I am going to try and do a fresh install on my home computer with the newer version of eclipse and see if that helps. Also, we are using the same apache tomcat version 9.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking in to consideration that you were able to connect to database and only issue was with respect to getting manufacturer id.

Try this
((BigInteger)rs.getInt("manufacturerID")).intValue()

Comment: Better rs.getObject(...) as rs.getInt() may be the cause.

Comment: But again whenever he transfer that code from jsp to some service or BL file and he needs to collect the data in to an variable it would be better to use appropriate data types instead of using generic type. Since he knows it is going to type of numeric why use object.

Comment: I'm suggesting Object only because resultset doesn't have getBigInteger which is the type referenced in the error. Perhaps getBigDecimal?

Comment: @Rohit Thank you for your suggestion but unfortunately I am getting an error saying BigInteger cannot be resolved to a type and also that it cannot invoke intValue() method on the primitive type int.

Comment: @MichaelMcKay Thank you, I have tried that it results in the same error as I've mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out the error, check the result set metadata.  From the docs, "The number, types and properties of a ResultSet object's columns are provided by the ResultSetMetaData object returned by the ResultSet.getMetaData method."  You could use this to try perhaps to change the column definition to numeric or another standard SQL type and see what you get.

```
int columnIndex = rs.findColumn("manufactuerID");
ResultSetMetaData myData = rs.GetMetaData();

// SQL type from java.sql.Types
System.out.println("Column Type: " +
myData.getColumnType(columnIndex));

// Type name used by the database.
System.out.println("Type name used by DB: " +
myData.getColumnTypeName(columnIndex));

// The fully-qualified name of the class in the Java programming 
// language that would be used by the method ResultSet.getObject
// to retrieve the value in the specified column.
System.out.println("Type name used by DB: " + 
myData.getColumnClassName(columnIndex));
```

Rereading your question though, its seems the issue may be more with setup than the code as you mention it worked on other computers.